# Append div between tr using backbone.js

Tags: html, backbone.js

I have this template for the table

```
<script id="allFaxesTemplate" type="text/template">
    <td><%= FaxSentDate %></td>
    <td><%= SentTime %></td>
    <td><%= FaxRecipient %></td>
    <td><%= FullName %></td>
    <td><%= FaxSubject %></td>
    <td><%= FaxCategory %></td>
    <td><%= NumberOfRequests %></td>

</script>
```

My Backbone views

```
/*
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Comment: All Faxes View ====> Table View
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

App.Views.Faxes = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',

    render: function () {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);        
        return this;
    },

    addOne: function (fax) {
        var faxView = new App.Views.Fax({ model: fax });
        //console.log(faxView.render().el);
        this.$el.append(faxView.render().el);
    }
});

/*
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Comment: Single Fax View ===> Row View
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

App.Views.Fax = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',

    template: template('allFaxesTemplate'),

    events: {
        'click': 'details'
    },

    /*
    initialize: function () {
    vent.on('QADetails:show', this.showDetails, this);
    },*/

    render: function () {
        var context = this.model.toJSON();
        context['FaxSentDate'] = this.getDateFormat(this.model.get('FaxSentDate'));
        context['SentTime'] = this.getTimeFormat(this.model.get('SentTime'));
        this.$el.html(this.template(context));

        return this;
    },

    details: function () {
        console.log(this.model.get('FaxID'));
        //console.log(this.model);
        vent.trigger('fax:details', this.model);        
    },

    //Change the date format from timespan
    getDateFormat: function (oldDate) {
        var newDate = new Date(parseInt(oldDate.substr(6)));
        return newDate.toDateString('MM-dd-yyyy');
    },
    //Change the time format from timespan
    getTimeFormat: function (oldTime) {
        var newTime = new Date(parseInt(oldTime.substr(6)));
        return newTime.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
});
```

Backbone view for displaying details of the row when clicked

```
/*
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Comment: Details View ===> Details per Row
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
App.Views.FaxDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: template('faxQADetails'),

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();        
    },

    render: function () {
        var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }

});
```

There's a template associated with the above view (code not shown).

So far it works in terms of displaying data, but it's not doing what I want it to do. I want the details of the row to show up with in the div when I click the row. Backbone appends the div, but it appends it between all trs. I just want it to append it only to the tr I clicked. Please help!

Thank you

Comment: You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<tr>`, `<tr>` can only hold `<td>`s and `<th>`s.

Comment: not inside <tr>, but after the <tr> that I clicked, and before the next <tr>, like: 
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <div></div>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>.... 
</tbody>

Comment: Having a `div` inside of a `tbody` is also invalid HTML. See "Permitted Contents" of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: You can't say `</tr><div></div><tr>`. The specs are actually pretty clear: start reading at [`<table>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/table.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. so what do you recommend? How can I have a box right below the tr that will expand and display the details when the row is clicked?